# Can windows server 2012 be installed on virtual box?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, operating-systems

(Private feedback for you)

Im trying to install windows server 2012 on virtual box via a bootable usb but it just reaches to this screen and hangs indefinitely, I've allocated 2GB of RAM and 15GB of space for the virtual HDD, not getting any error messages just stuck at this screen.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5cvrN.jpg)

Comment: (This has obviously been resubmitted without any improvements)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [Microsoft system requirements](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/dn303418(v=ws.11)), Windows Server 2012 requires a partition of not less than 32GB.